# Conditionally replace substring in a string

Tags: python, string, replace

I have a string that looks like-

`str1="lol-tion haha-futures-tion yo-tion ard-tion pomo-tion"`

I want to replace the substring `tion` with `cloud` **IF** it has only 1 `-` between lol and tion `lol-tion`

`str2=str1.replace('tion','cloud')`

But when the word has two `-` like instance`haha-futures-tion` I want to replace it like below-

`str3=str1.replace('tion','')`

Expecting output-> `haha-futures`

How can I accomplish both these conditional replacements?

Comment: Please include the exact output you expect based on the input `str1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code with regex and condition,

```
import re
str1="lol-tion haha-futures-tion yo-tion ard-tion pomo-tion"
str2=""
for sub_string in str1.split(' '):
    if re.search(r'^[a-z,-]+-tion$', sub_string):
        if re.match(r"[a-zA-Z]+[-][a-zA-Z]+-tion$",sub_string):
            print("match")
            sub_string=sub_string.replace('tion','')
        else:
            sub_string=sub_string.replace('tion','cloud')
        print(sub_string)
    str2+=sub_string+" "
print(str2)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC this will work:

```
new_str1 = ' '.join([string.strip('-tion') 
                     if string.count('-')==2 
                     else string.replace('tion','cloud') 
                     for string in str1.split(' ')])
print(new_str1)

'lol-cloud haha-futures yo-cloud ard-cloud pomo-cloud'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description isn't really clear, nor does it fully specify what should happen in all cases, but here's one interpretation:

```py
def replace_tion(word):
    replacements = {1: 'cloud', 2: ''}
    replacement = replacements.get(word.count('-'), 'tion')
    return word.replace('tion', replacement)

str1 = "lol-tion haha-futures-tion yo-tion ard-tion pomo-tion"
tions_replaced = ' '.join(replace_tion(word) for word in str1.split(' '))

# 'lol-cloud haha-futures- yo-cloud ard-cloud pomo-cloud'
```

Comment: My bad, I edited it to be more clear. I hope it's understandable now